# $f$ is holomorphic then there exists $F$ such that $f=exp(F)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain and $f$ is a holomorphic function with no zeros in $\Omega$. Suppose for infinitely many positive integer $k$, $f$ has a holomorphic $k$ th root. Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $F$ such that $ f=e^F$.

My try:
I guess the argument principle might be useful here. But i don’t know how to prove it. When domain is simply connected, such result can be proved by letting $F(z)=F(z_0)+\int_{z_0}^z\frac{f’}{f}$.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719283/42969 – that proof works for your case as well.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, I think so. Should I close it or delete it?